# DRF - How to get WritableField to not load entire database into memory?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a very large database (6 GB) that I would like to use Django-REST-Framework with. In particular, I have a model that has a ForeignKey relationship to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` table (not so big) and a Foreign Key to a BIG table (lets call it Products). The model can be seen below:

```
class ShoppingBag(models.Model):

    user     = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='+')
    product  = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Product', related_name='+')
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

Again, there are 6GB of Products.

The serializer is as follows:

```
class ShoppingBagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = serializers.RelatedField(many=False)
    user    = serializers.RelatedField(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model  = ShoppingBag
        fields = ('product', 'user', 'quantity')
```

So far this is great- I can do a GET on the list and individual shopping bags, and everything is fine. For reference the queries (using a query logger) look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_product WHERE product_id=1254
SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE user_id=12
SELECT * FROM myapp_product WHERE product_id=1404
SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE user_id=12
...
```

For as many shopping bags are getting returned.

But I would like to be able to `POST` to create new shopping bags, but `serializers.RelatedField` is read-only. Let's make it read-write:

```
class ShoppingBagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)
    user    = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)

    ...
```

Now things get bad... `GET` requests to the `list` action take > 5 minutes and I noticed that my server's memory jumps up to ~6GB; why?! Well, back to the SQL queries and now I see:

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_products;
SELECT * FROM auth_user;
```

Ok, so that's not good. Clearly we're doing "prefetch related" or "select_related" or something like that in order to get access to all the products; but this table is HUGE.

Further inspection reveals where this happens on [Line 68 of relations.py in DRF](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L68):

```
def initialize(self, parent, field_name):
    super(RelatedField, self).initialize(parent, field_name)
    if self.queryset is None and not self.read_only:
        manager = getattr(self.parent.opts.model, self.source or field_name)
        if hasattr(manager, 'related'):  # Forward
            self.queryset = manager.related.model._default_manager.all()
        else:  # Reverse
            self.queryset = manager.field.rel.to._default_manager.all()
```

If not readonly, self.queryset = ALL!!

So, I'm pretty sure that this is where my problem is; and I need to say, don't select_related here, but I'm not 100% if this is the issue or where to deal with this. It seems like all should be memory safe with pagination, but this is simply not the case. I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, we had to simply create our own `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` class to override the default behavior in Django-Rest-Framework. Basically we ensured that the queryset was None until we wanted to lookup the object, then we performed the lookup. This was extremely annoying, and I hope the Django-Rest-Framework guys take note of this!

Our final solution:

```
class ProductField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    many = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwarsgs['queryset'] = Product.objects.none() # Hack to ensure ALL products are not loaded
        super(ProductField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        return unicode(obj)

    def from_native(self, data):
        """
        Perform query lookup here.
        """
        try:
            return Product.objects.get(pk=data)
        except Product.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            msg = self.error_messages['does_not_exist'] % smart_text(data)
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            msg = self.error_messages['incorrect_type'] % type(data)
            raise ValidationError(msg)
```

And then our serializer is as follows:

```
class ShoppingBagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = ProductField()
    ...
```

This hack ensures the entire database isn't loaded into memory, but rather performs one-off selects based on the data. It's not as efficient computationally, but it also doesn't blast our server with 5 second database queries loaded into memory!